# Get the Name of the object ddplyed upon

Tags: r, plyr

maybe I use the wrong searchterms, or this is not really possible:

I use ddply to print out lots of graphs. In the function to do this, I'd like to make a subdirectory, where all these plots end up in.

This itself is no problem. But instead of passing a directory name as extra input parameter, I'd like the function to somehow read the name of the dataframe I ddplyed on.

So far, I use this approach:

```
myplotfunction <- function(x,df_name){
      p=ggplot (...)
      ggsave(file.path(getwd,df_name,paste0(x$name,".png"),plot=p)
}

ddply(mydfIddplyUpon,.(name),myplotfunction,df_name="mydfIddplyUpon")
```

But if I could get the function to find out the name of the df, which was split by plyr, this would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a wrapper function,

```
nddply <- function(x, var, fun, ...){
  xn <- deparse(substitute(x))
  plyr::ddply(x, var, fun, ..., directory_name = xn)
}

# where fun is your function that needs a directory_name
fun <- function(a, directory_name, ...)
  paste(nrow(a),  directory_name, ...)

nddply(iris, "Species", fun, sep=", from: ")
```

---

Edit: here's an example saving plots

```
nd_ply <- function(x, var, fun, ...){
  xn <- deparse(substitute(x))
  plyr::d_ply(x, var, fun, ..., directory_name = xn)
}

fun <- function(a, directory_name, ...)
  ggsave(paste0(directory_name, unique(a$Species), ".pdf"), 
         ggplot(a, aes_string(x="Sepal.Length", y="Sepal.Width", ...))+ geom_point())

nd_ply(iris, "Species", fun, colour="Sepal.Length")
```

Comment: Thanks! However I am not sure, if I understand that really. Where would the commands that generate the plot go? in fun? so far I did not get it to work...

Comment: after some tinkering and the usual trial and error, I got it. Actually you explained well enough, I just seem to have been to tired last night. Thanks again